# ffmpeg command x265 param option for android device

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-encoding, hevc

I wanto encode HEVC video to be played on my android phone.

[in this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#video-formats) from anroid says that only Lollipop+ will supported HEVC. and the Profile : main, Level 3.

But ffmpeg encoding x265 not supproted profiling. I know some answer of [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/935930/setting-the-profile-level-for-libx265-using-ffmpeg), But thats is for Profile main10. I need -x265-param for profile: main, Level : 3.

this option is for Profile Main level 10 :

```
-x265-params keyint=1:ref=1:no-open-gop=1:weightp=0:weightb=0:cutree=0:rc- 
lookahead=0:bframes=0:scenecut=0:b-adapt=0:repeat-headers=1 <output_filename>
```

how about for level 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `level-idc=30` to x265-params for level 3.0. The actual level set may be lower, which is fine. If you use a recent git build or 4.0 release, you can add `-profile main` to the command for setting profile.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libx265 -b:v 300k -x265-params keyint=1:ref=1:no-open-gop=1:weightp=0:weightb=0:cutree=0:rc-lookahead=0:bframes=0:scenecut=0:b-adapt=0:repeat-headers=1:level-idc=30 out.mp4` i use that but show `Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`

Comment: Share full log.